# Google Chrome & Chromium Display Glitch

Tags: apt, google-chrome, chromium

When i lock my screen or even the screen turns off (after screen timeout) google-chrome-browser or chromium browser behaves the same as this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIvMp.jpg); if i scroll down, the blue color of the man's T-shirt will fill the screen.

This issue does not occur in chromium from snap. it only occurs from apt.

What i tried:

1- manually removing everything related to google-chrome-browser and chromium-browser (by purging and removing conf files and manually searching for any leftover files) and then reinstalling them.

2- reinstalling chromium-browser and each and every dependency it needs `$sudo apt install libatspi2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libdrm2 libexpat1  libgbm1 libgcc1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0  libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxrandr2 libxtst6 bash xdg-utils --reinstall`

3-checked if this issue occurs in my 2nd pc but it does not.

what i suspect:

1- I had an issue before with firefox (2 years ago as both of chrome and firefox where using the same file but different version and since then i installed firefox using `snap` and chrome using `apt`, and when i though of removing firefox `snap` and install it from `apt` this issue occured. the point is that the same pc i tested this glitch on -and it did not occur- have also firefox and chromium -just like my laptop-

chrome is the only program on my laptop that does this glitch (tested every program i had). The only way to resolve this is to close and reopen chrome.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling linux again i found out that specific nvidia drivers (nvidia 440 & 450) is the source of the issue. Nouveau drivers makes things a lot stable.